# SQL Trigger, Update view after insert

Tags: mysql, sql, view, triggers

I'm working on a database for a school project. I want to create a trigger, that updates a view and sorts it ascending, after data has been inserted into the view.

Thats what I have at the moment. I would be thankful if you guys could help me, thank you!

```
 AFTER INSERT
 AS
 UPDATE vw_Highscore
```

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? Storing your data sorted sounds wrong anyway, you should sort it when you query it. The official documentation shows the correct for triggers. And you need to clarify what your update should actually do.

Comment: im working on MySQL

Comment: @zjxstin Am I missed something? Quote from [official MySQL site](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/faqs-views.html#faq-mysql-have-materialized-views): *A.6.5. Does MySQL 8.0 have materialized views? | No.* What are you going to update in vew, that is essentially just a saved `SELECT` statement?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean to sort by one specific column in ascending order on the view table. Well that's easy. You definitely don't need a trigger for that. Simply include the Primary key, or any index in your view table.

When you have a primary key or any type of index placed on your tables, they will automatically be stored in ascending order because of how BTREE indexes work. So when you query them they will always be sorted unless another index overrides them. Primary key overrides all other indexes in most cases. However, if you want to include a primary key in the query, but sort by something else, then use the `ORDER BY` clause.

For example, say I have a `customer` table with ID, name and address column. When I do `SELECT * FROM customer;` I would get this result:

```
ID    name
1     John
2     Adam
3     Sue
```

Notice how the id is sorted and the `name` column is not?

If I then change my query to be `SELECT * FROM customer ORDER BY name;` Now I will get this result:

```
ID    name
2     Adam
1     John
3     Sue
```

Since your view table is synced with the base tables this means you should always have up-to-date sorted results on your view.

Alternatively, if you want to hard code it into your view table without relying on indexes at all, then just use this syntax for your create view statement:
`CREATE VIEW view_name AS SELECT * FROM base_table ORDER BY column.`

Now your view will always be storing its results in sorted format by the column you specify in the `ORDER BY` section.

Besides the solutions I mentioned above, you could also try and make a CREATE TRIGGER statement. But based on your question as is, that seems like a over-complicated and pointless way to do it. Updating a view is the same as updating it's base table, so if an insert statement is taking place, then that is already going to update your view table automatically. And if like I mentioned above, you have a index or primary key from the base table included in your view or you used `ORDER BY` clause in your `CREATE VIEW` statement, then it will sort itself alphabetically/numerically in Ascending order without you needing to take additional steps.

Comment: I didn't find the points in the official documentation, but in SQL the only way to guarantee row order is `ORDER BY` clause. But it should be used outside the view and totally is part of data retrieval task.

Comment: Indeed, I had to search for a while to find this stated explicitly: "There are three phases to an index build. In the first phase, the clustered index is scanned, and index entries are generated and added to the sort buffer. ... In the second phase, with one or more runs written to the temporary intermediate file, a merge sort is performed on all entries in the file. In the third and final phase, the sorted entries are inserted into the B-tree." - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sorted-index-builds.html     So you don't need to specify ASC in index, but DESC is required for descending.

Comment: Of course index is stored in sorted way, this is how B-tree works. My statement was about the query result, which should be sorted explicitly with `ORDER BY` without relying on some structures or storage type.

Comment: Oh I see. Yes, I agree with you there. I was simply showing a method by which the original questioner would be able to get data stored as sorted data without needing to update with triggers if they were adamant about doing that particular thing.  But Order By is definitely the best way to go about sorting, no argument here.